# Relationship between singular values and eigenvalues of a square matrix A?

Tags: matrices, svd

What is the relationship between the singular values and the eigenvalues of $$AA^T$$ if $A$ is a square matrix (if that even matters)?

So what I did:

$$AA^T = USV^TVSU^T = USSU^T = US^2U^T$$

I read on google that the singular values of $A$ are the square root of the eigenvalues of $AA^T$ but I don't really know how to derive this from the equation above (or at all)?

Any hints how I can proof this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the relationship exactly. If you take the eigen decomposition of $AA^T$ just rewrite it.

$$ AA^T = U \Sigma^{2} U^T = U \Lambda U^T $$

where $\Lambda$ is the matrix of eigenvalues for $AA^T$. If $\Sigma^{2} = \Lambda$ then

$$ \sigma_{i} = \sqrt{\lambda_{i}} $$

Note that $AA^T$ is positive semidefinite so the eigenvalues are non-negative. If you multiply a diagonal matrix with another diagonal matrix it just multiplies each element by the other one so this squares them.